# karma tests on chromium

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome, chromium, karma-runner

Is it possible to run karma tests with chromium browser, in order to run these karma tests on linux box which has an open source version of chrome in it?

Comment: You chose the wrong answer

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could also set the CHROME_BIN environment variable to chromium

```
export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Comment: For me it was `export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium`

Comment: This [isn't needed any more](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/commit/46e14284ef9bd575ec88b9e62f36f81aaedd56d2). I didn't have to do it for karma-chrome-launcher 0.2.0.

Comment: this worked for me, i was able to run my test with chromium-browser while keeping my karma.conf.js option as browsers: ['Chrome'],

Comment: @z0r seems to be required again for Angular 2+